# Find and match elements in a column and change the values of corresponding rows in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, string-matching

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['A','B','A','C','C'], 'value':[2,4,9,1,3.5]})
df
  ID  value
0  A    2.0
1  B    4.0
2  A    9.0
3  C    1.0
4  C    3.5
```

What I need to do is to go through `ID` column and for each unique value, find that row, and multiply the corresponding row in `value` column based on the reference that I have.

For example, if I have the following **reference**:

```
if A multiply by 10
if B multiply by 3
if C multiply by 2
```

Then the desired output would be:

```
df
  ID  value
0  A    2.0*10
1  B    4.0*3
2  A    9.0*10
3  C    1.0*2
4  C    3.5*2
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with dictionary for Series used for multiple column `value`:

```
d = {'A':10, 'B':3,'C':2}
df['value'] = df['value'].mul(df['ID'].map(d))

print (df)
  ID  value
0  A   20.0
1  B   12.0
2  A   90.0
3  C    2.0
4  C    7.0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['ID'].map(d))
0    10
1     3
2    10
3     2
4     2
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Fast, genius, and effective solution as usual. Thanks a lot.